# Dokumente ablegen

Tags: mysql

gibt es in Civi eine Möglichkeit Dokumente, Bilder, Dateien abzulegen?

In der Demo Version finde ich die Möglichkeit nicht.

Vielen Dank für Eure Mühe.

Beste Grüße
Horst

Comment: Although you can certainly ask questions in German, the odds on getting lots of answers are bigger when you ask in English :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are asking really. There are parts of CiviCRM where you can add attachments.
Also there is the documents extension, you can read more about it here: https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/using-and-improving-the-documents-extension-a-drupal-extension-by-civicoop

But in general you would need to tell us what kind of documents you want to save and the exact functional requirement.